# Steam Guard requires a Steam Guard code to login

Tags: steam

1. I log into store.steampowered.com
2. Being asked for a Steam Guard 1-time code
3. Opened Steam android app (Steam Guard is there)
4. For some reason now the app asks me for a Steam Guard 1-time code
5. x_x

Is there an exit from that loop?

Comment: Isnt there a button beside the "confirm code" one saying you have no access to the steam guard?

Comment: Check your email, likely the code has been sent there

Answer (score -2):

You reset by a SMS code.

I got this issue during the summer sale. I was trying to trade some cards and couldn't get notifications to show up, no errors no warnings, no nothing. So I reset the authenticator suggested by some users. Now I have to wait 15 days.

Comment: The trading cards from the current Summer Sale expire a month after the sale ends, which is over a week away.